# How to implement Fragment within Navigational Drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I already have fragments working on navigational drawer clicks using:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 int id = item.getItemId();
 if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
 // desired fragment to load
}
```

What i want is when i open the app, first thing is to check whether user is already logged in, which can be done using shared preferences. If yes, then open main Home page of the app which is working fine. But, if he is not, then i want to show Login Fragment Page.
I want to achieve this with only activities provided when you create project using navigation drawer activity. Any Solutions ?
Activities in Project:
1. Home Activity which is the main activity.
2. Internal Activity which is only managing fragments when user clicks on navigational drawer list.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
if(userIsLoggedIn(){  //Check from SharedPreference
      fragment = new MainFragment();
 } else {
      fragment = new LoginFragment();
 }

 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            fragment = new CameraFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, fragment).commit();
        assert drawer != null;
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
```